# Mapping tab changes in vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to do a key mapping in vim, yet it doesn't appear to be working how I want it to:

In my `~.vimrc` file I have:

```
syntax on
colorscheme delek
nnoremap < gt
nnoremap > gT
```

(I only include the first two comments to show that I know my `.vimrc` is working).

Yet, after I save the file, using `<` or `>` does not do anything, though `gt` and `gT` are still changing tabs as expected. What is wrong with my character mapping? Or do I need to 'refresh vim' or something, the equivalent of `$ source ~/.bash_profile` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that there is nothing wrong with your mapping, and that you are correct about needing to reload/refresh your configuration for it to actually be available. One way to do so is to restart Vim, but we can do it faster with the `:so` (short for `:source`) command and the `$MYVIMRC` environment variable:

```
:so $MYVIMRC
```

Comment: great, thank you. And! I forgot to press the `:w`, so I was reloading it a bunch of times with forgetting to first save it.